# How can i use groupby in Tri gram in NLP

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

How do i use groupby with tri gram. I am getting error as - AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'lower'

```
## Creating Part_Description GROUPBY Object
incidents_Part_Description= df1.groupby("Part_Description")

word_vectorizer = CountVectorizer(ngram_range=(3,3), analyzer='word')
sparse_matrix = word_vectorizer.fit_transform(incidents_Part_Description["Description"])

frequencies = sum(sparse_matrix).toarray()[0]
tri_grams_df = pd.DataFrame(frequencies, index=word_vectorizer.get_feature_names(), columns=['frequency'])
```

Comment: `CountVectorizer.fit` is expecting an iterable of strings.

Comment: any idea. how to deal with it?

Comment: You provide it an iterable of strings instead of a groupby object. :-)

Comment: also tried to use a groupby see below. but ended with error.                                                                                                             word_vectorizer = CountVectorizer(ngram_range=(3,3), analyzer='word')
sparse_matrix = word_vectorizer.fit_transform(df1.groupby("Part_Description")["Description"])
frequencies = sum(sparse_matrix).toarray()[0]
tri_grams_df = pd.DataFrame(frequencies, index=word_vectorizer.get_feature_names(), columns=['frequency'])